# PHP Map infinite objects

Tags: php, laravel

I have some struggles how to map infinite object in Laravel.

So I have one table Categories that I'm getting in controller like:

```
$find_parent = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('childrenRecursive')->first();
```

`childrenRecursive()` works fine in that case.

And return of this object would be like (minified):

```
{
    "id": "1cbd459a-ccc0-435b-b9a9-0433e2e9285b",
    "parent_id": "f0d29100-d2bc-48c8-89cf-985e0c03b8ac",
    "children_recursive": [
        {
            "id": "30bf23a7-b28c-4s78-b873-1df589eebcb1",
            "parent_id": "1cbd459a-ccc0-435b-b9a9-0433e2e9285b",
            "children_recursive": [
                {
                    "id": "32312a7-b28c-4s78-b873-1df589eebcb1",
                    "parent_id": "30bf23a7-b28c-4s78-b873-1df589eebcb1",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "32bf23a7-b28c-4s78-b873-1df589eebcb1",
            "parent_id": "1cbd459a-ccc0-435b-b9a9-0433e2e9285b",
            "children_recursive": []
        }
    ]
}
```

So from this, I have to get all id's in every object. So I have foreach function in controller that looks like:

```
        $find_parent = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('childrenRecursive')->first();
        $array = [];

        foreach($find_parent->childrenRecursive as $l){
            array_push($array, $l->id);
            if($l->childrenRecursive){
                    $result = array_merge($array, $this->catTree($l->childrenRecursive));
            }
        }


        return $result;
```

And catTree would look like:

```
public function catTree($list){
        $tree = [];

        foreach($list as $l){
            array_push($tree, $l->id);

            if($l->childrenRecursive){
                array_merge($tree, $this->catTree($l->childrenRecursive));
            }
        }

        return $tree;
    }
```

So this is returning some of the objects, but not everything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `array_merge` return a new array you should affect it to `$tree` variable

Comment: @Yanis-git is correct, use this: `$tree = array_merge($tree, $this->catTree($l->childrenRecursive));`